# Search methods datastructures

Tags: search, methods, time-complexity, big-o

I have a problem with a question in a paper that was handed out to me which I am hoping that someone will be able to give me some help with. The question is:

a) The little book of birds with 100 headwords and the big book of birds with 1000 headwords is stored in a computer searchable form. It takes approximately 50% as long time to search through the big bird book as the small bird book. Which search method is used?

b) Now the storing- and search method is exchanged. Now it takes the same amount of time to search through both books. Which is the new search method?

So the first question is of complexity O(log(n)) and I don't know any search method with that time complexity. The second one should be of order O(1), as they take the same amount of time??

Answer (score 1):

[Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) has asymptotic complexity `O(log n)`. If the length of headwords is assumed to be constant, a [hash-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) algorithm can retrieve elements in constant time, see e.g [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).